# HighCharts - barchart not rendering correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I have a simple barchart which does not render correctly under IE8 (columns are not visible). It does display correctly with firefox and IE 9+.

I'am using jQuery 1.8.3 and highcharts 3.0.3.

I keep datas in the code sample because the number of columns to draw is important in reproducing the problem. The graph renders correctly in IE8 if I remove one serie.

Here is the code :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var barOptions = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                width:450,
                height:350,
                type: 'column'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'NC',
                data: [7057, 6858, 6643, 6570, 6115, 107, 31, 635, 203, 2, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'OK',
                data: [54047, 52484, 50591, 49479, 46677, 33, 156, 947, 408, 6, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'KO',
                data: [11388, 11115, 10742, 10757, 10290, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'VALID',
                data: [8836, 8509, 8255, 7760, 7621, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'CHECK',
                data: [115, 162, 150, 187, 172, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'COR',
                data: [12566, 12116, 11446, 10749, 10439, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
            }]
        };

       barChart = new Highcharts.Chart(barOptions);
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this looks like a bug in Highcharts. A workaround would be to hide and show one of the series programmatically right after the chart is rendered.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ykR/). Try it in [IE8 here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ykR/show/).

```
$(function () {
    var barOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            width: 450,
            height: 350,
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'NC',
            data: [7057, 6858, 6643, 6570, 6115, 107, 31, 635, 203, 2, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'OK',
            data: [54047, 52484, 50591, 49479, 46677, 33, 156, 947, 408, 6, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'KO',
            data: [11388, 11115, 10742, 10757, 10290, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'VALID',
            data: [8836, 8509, 8255, 7760, 7621, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'CHECK',
            data: [115, 162, 150, 187, 172, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'COR',
            data: [12566, 12116, 11446, 10749, 10439, 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34, 2]
        }]
    };

    barChart = new Highcharts.Chart(barOptions);
    barChart.series[0].hide();
    barChart.series[0].show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bug, reported to our developers: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2091